# How to delete first tag when to same tags are over each other in xml

Tags: xml, python-3.7

Hello friends when I have two or three tags `<word>` over each other it effect my reading for the file like the following example

```
<word wordid="&lt;bon_Aljanuwb_1" value="إبْن الجَنُوب" synsetid="Aljanuwbiy_n1AR" frequency="1" corpus="manchester20060717" authorshipid="12030" />
<word wordid="&lt;bon__1" value="إبْن البَلَد" synsetid="&lt;ibon_Albalad_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12031" />
<word wordid="&lt;bonap_1" value="إبْنَة" synsetid="&lt;ibonap_n2AR" frequency="1" corpus="manchester20060717" authorshipid="12032" />
<word wordid="&lt;bonu__1" value="إبْنُ عُرْس" synsetid="&lt;ibonu_Euros_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12033" />
<word wordid="&lt;borAhAm__1" value="إبْراهام لينْكون" synsetid="&lt;iborAhAm_lynokwn_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12034" />
<word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035" />
<form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035" />
```

what i am trying to do is to delete all the word tags and keep the one that is followed with the tag from to produce the output

```
<word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035" />
<form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035" />
```

however, a bigger view of the file is attached in the following line, where the correct results should be without the first line any ides please

```
<word wordid="&lt;borAhAm__1" value="إبْراهام لينْكون" synsetid="&lt;iborAhAm_lynokwn_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12034" />
<word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035" />
<form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035" />
<word wordid="&lt;botaz~a_1" value="إبْتَزَّ" synsetid="&lt;ibotaz~a_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12036" />
<form value="بزز" wordid="&lt;botaz~a_1" type="root" authorshipid="12036" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [xpath in lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to select any `word` when the first following sibling is another `word` and remove it.

Example...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <test>
        <word wordid="&lt;bon_Aljanuwb_1" value="إبْن الجَنُوب" synsetid="Aljanuwbiy_n1AR" frequency="1" corpus="manchester20060717" authorshipid="12030" />
        <word wordid="&lt;bon__1" value="إبْن البَلَد" synsetid="&lt;ibon_Albalad_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12031" />
        <word wordid="&lt;bonap_1" value="إبْنَة" synsetid="&lt;ibonap_n2AR" frequency="1" corpus="manchester20060717" authorshipid="12032" />
        <word wordid="&lt;bonu__1" value="إبْنُ عُرْس" synsetid="&lt;ibonu_Euros_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12033" />
        <word wordid="&lt;borAhAm__1" value="إبْراهام لينْكون" synsetid="&lt;iborAhAm_lynokwn_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12034" />
        <word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035" />
        <form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035" />
    </test>
    <test>
        <word wordid="&lt;borAhAm__1" value="إبْراهام لينْكون" synsetid="&lt;iborAhAm_lynokwn_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12034" />
        <word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035" />
        <form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035" />
        <word wordid="&lt;botaz~a_1" value="إبْتَزَّ" synsetid="&lt;ibotaz~a_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12036" />
        <form value="بزز" wordid="&lt;botaz~a_1" type="root" authorshipid="12036" />
    </test>
</doc>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

for to_remove in tree.xpath("//word[following-sibling::*[1][self::word]]"):
    to_remove.getparent().remove(to_remove)

tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

**XML Output** (output.xml)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<doc>
    <test>
        <word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035"/>
        <form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035"/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <word wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" value="إبْتَهَجَ" synsetid="fariHa_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12035"/>
        <form value="بهج" wordid="&lt;botahaja_1" type="root" authorshipid="12035"/>
        <word wordid="&lt;botaz~a_1" value="إبْتَزَّ" synsetid="&lt;ibotaz~a_v1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="12036"/>
        <form value="بزز" wordid="&lt;botaz~a_1" type="root" authorshipid="12036"/>
    </test>
</doc>
```

Comment: Tq brother just note there is not <test> tags it's over each others